# Distribute elements in a container with Bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm rewriting my site to Bootstrap3 and stumbled upon an error that seems to hit many people as well. Basically I'm trying to distribute evenly 4 ~220px elements inside a 990px container. In old bootstrap, margins were added automatically. But right now there's no such thing anymore with their padding approach. Any tips how to tackle this ?

Here's a sample code :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <section class="col-md-12">
        <article class="col-md-3">content</article>
        <article class="col-md-3">content2</article>
        <article class="col-md-3">content3</article>
        <article class="col-md-3">content4</article>
    </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

And fiddle link :

http://jsfiddle.net/QJyCe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I use the "col-" div as a container and then place the content html inside:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <article>
            article1
        </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <article>
            article2
        </article>        
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <article>
            article3
        </article>        
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <article>
            article4
        </article>        
    </div>    
</div>

@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
article { height:100px; padding:20px; border: 1px solid black; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/25BHu/1/

Comment: Gah, I've missed this in the initial question. What I meant was to distribute them horizontally, not vertically. Do you think this would work here as well ?